# How to use Docker Compose file with Next.js, Prisma, and SQLite

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, prisma

I have a next 14 app that uses Prisma as the ORM and am using a Sqlite db locally for dev testing. I don't want to use an image for MySQL or Mongo or Postgres etc...

In trying to use `docker compose` I am having issues running the container and having the project show up on port 3000.

The specific error:

```
Server Error
Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
In case this error is unexpected for you, please report it in https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
src/db/index.ts (3:22) @ eval

  1 | import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
  2 |
> 3 | export const prisma = new PrismaClient();
```

Dockerfile

```
# set the base image to create the image for react app
FROM node:20-alpine

# create a user with permissions to run the app
# -S -> create a system user
# -G -> add the user to a group
# This is done to avoid running the app as root
# If the app is run as root, any vulnerability in the app can be exploited to gain access to the host system
# It's a good practice to run the app as a non-root user
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app

# set the user to run the app
USER app

# set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
# This is done before copying the rest of the files to take advantage of Docker’s cache
# If the package.json and package-lock.json files haven’t changed, Docker will use the cached dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
COPY ./prisma prisma

# sometimes the ownership of the files in the working directory is changed to root
# and thus the app can't access the files and throws an error -> EACCES: permission denied
# to avoid this, change the ownership of the files to the root user
USER root

# change the ownership of the /app directory to the app user
# chown -R <user>:<group> <directory>
# chown command changes the user and/or group ownership of for given file.
RUN chown -R app:app .

# change the user back to the app user
USER app

# init prisma
RUN npx prisma generate --schema=./prisma/schema.prisma

# install dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy the rest of the files to the working directory
COPY . .

# expose port 3000 to tell Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime
EXPOSE 3000

# command to run the app
CMD npm run dev
```

Compose.yaml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: file:./prisma/dev.db
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - /app/prisma
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

My prisma stuff lives in the root-dir/prisma. In there I have:
`prisma/dev.db`
`prisma/schema.prisma`
`prisma/migrations/20231227173804_intial_migration`

I tried running a cache free re build of my docker image and also tried the `prisma generate` with and without the specific `--schema` flag.

How do I get this to run my docker container using `docker compose up`?

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing I'd try to change is the `volumes:` block, which overwrites pretty much everything your image does with a combination of host files and anonymous Docker volumes.  Does deleting the `volumes:` block improve things?  More specifically, the `volumes:` will hide the result of `RUN npx prisma generate`.

Comment: Commenting out `volumes` did allow me to run the application in the container but when loading it, the next auth/oauth flow I have fails because it can't find a connection to a sqlite db containing users. Error: Error occurred during query execution:
web-1  | ConnectorError(ConnectorError { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(SqliteError { extended_code: 8, message: Some("attempt to write a readonly database") }), transient: false })

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had an permissions issue that caused the prisma, dev.db files/dirs to be owned by `root` instead of the `app` user I am appointing in my `Dockerfile`. I also needed to re-run a docker compose command and exclude cache so it didn't use previous configurations.

Updated:

Dockerfile

```
# set the base image to create the image for react app
FROM node:20-alpine

# create a user with permissions to run the app
# -S -> create a system user
# -G -> add the user to a group
# This is done to avoid running the app as root
# If the app is run as root, any vulnerability in the app can be exploited to gain access to the host system
# It's a good practice to run the app as a non-root user
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app

# set the user to run the app
USER app

# set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
# This is done before copying the rest of the files to take advantage of Docker’s cache
# If the package.json and package-lock.json files haven’t changed, Docker will use the cached dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
COPY ./prisma prisma
COPY ./dev.db /app/dev.db

# sometimes the ownership of the files in the working directory is changed to root
# and thus the app can't access the files and throws an error -> EACCES: permission denied
# to avoid this, change the ownership of the files to the root user
USER root

# Ensure write permissions for the app directory and its contents
RUN chmod -R u+w .

# change the ownership of the /app directory to the app user
# chown -R <user>:<group> <directory>
# chown command changes the user and/or group ownership of for given file.
RUN chown -R app:app .

# As root, change the ownership of dev.db to app user
RUN chown app:app dev.db

# change the user back to the app user
USER app

# init prisma
RUN npx prisma generate --schema=./prisma/schema.prisma

# install dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy the rest of the files to the working directory
COPY . .

# expose port 3000 to tell Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime
EXPOSE 3000

# command to run the app
CMD npm run dev
```

compose.yaml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: file:./dev.db
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - /app/prisma
      - ./dev.db:/app/dev.db:rw # Mount the database file with correct ownership
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

Commands:

1. `docker-compose build --no-cache`
2. `docker compose up`

After this, I was able to write to my sqlite db with prisma orm inside of a Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a different but [more secure way for Drizzle + SQLite + Next.js.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78034830/6141587) I think the use is same for Prisma although [this solution is probably closer except he uses Nest JS.](https://notiz.dev/blog/prisma-migrate-deploy-with-docker)